# WP8 Webbrowser control showing security warning but the same URL (HTTPS) works fine on phone IE

Tags: windows-phone-8, https, webbrowser-control

I am developing a windows phone application but little stuck on an issue. I simply trying
to access a site (HTTPS) through webbrowser control. It showing security warning ( We are we're having trouble with this site's security certificate..)

Surprisingly, the same URL (HTTPS) works fine on IE ( phone browser ) in the same windows phone . I am able to view the content perfectly for some other HTTPS sites ( https://www.google.ae , https://www.wikipedia.org/) using the webbrowser control.

What is the problem with that site ?? or what am I missing??

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the actual certificate

Comment: Thanks for your response. [link](https://qayed.sca.ae/) this is the URL I am using.